# Creating a new list in a for loop

Tags: python, loops

Let's say I have two lists `v` and `n` created as shown and I need to create a new list `Q2` such that `Q2[i] = (v[i] , n[i])`.

```
 n = [x * 0.1 for x in range(0, 11)]
>>> n
[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]


v = [((x**2)+ 2*x) for x in n]
>>> v
[0.0, 0.21, 0.44, 0.69, 0.96, 1.25, 1.56, 1.89, 2.24, 2.61, 3.0]
```

I tried list comprehension but it gives me a matrix of all the individual elements

```
Q2 = [(x,y) for x in v for y in n]
```

I have been trying to write it in a for loop but it seems there is an issue with the syntax.

```
for i in range(len(n) -1): 
Q2[i] = (v[i],n[i])
```

the error I get using the above for loop is

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

How would I go about creating a new list in the for loop?

Comment: *expected an indented block* - Learn to write a for-loop, it needs to be indented https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: Use `Q2 = zip(v, n)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that lines within a for/while loop (or if/else/def/try/except for that matter) need to be indented. What you wanted was this:

```
for i in range(len(n) -1):
    Q2[i] = (v[i],n[i])
```

If you really wanted to do this with a loop:

```
Q2 = []
for i in range(len(n)):
    Q2.append((v[i], n[i]))
```

List comprehension:

```
Q2 = [(v[i], n[i]) for i in range(len(n))]
```

More pythonic way:

```
Q2 = list(zip(v, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about python indentation.

Also note: the last integer generated by range() is up to, but not including, the value you specified.
You don't need the '-1'

This indented code works:

```
for i in range(len(n)):
    Q2[i] = (v[i],n[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is close. Use nested iterators to generate the items

```
# making the list in multiple steps
n = [x * 0.1 for x in range(0, 11)]
v = [((x**2)+ 2*x) for x in n]
q2 = list(zip(n,v))
print('want', q2)

# making the list in one step
q2 = [(y, (y**2)+2*y) for y in ((x*0.1) for x in range(11))]
print('got', q2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python works on the ideas of blocks so the next line of the for loop should be indented by either four spaces or tabbed (or whatever you have set up)

```
for x in a_list:
    print(x)
```